# In what sense does the sequence of functions $\big\{\frac{x}{x+i}\big\}_{i\in\mathbb{R}}$ converge to the constant function $1_\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus

Let $1_\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the identity function on $\mathbb{R}$. In what sense does the sequence of functions $\big\{\frac{x}{x+i}\big\}_{i\in\mathbb{R}}$ converge to $1_\mathbb{R}$ as $i\rightarrow 0$?

When $i\in\mathbb{R^+}$, the graph of the function $\frac{x}{x+i}$ is a hyperbola, even for arbitrarily small values of $i$. However, at $i=0$, the function $\frac{x}{x+i}$ abruptly turns into a straight line.

How is this type of "convergence" called? Can it be called convergence at all?

Comment: Certainly it's pointwise convergence.  I don't think you can say much else about it, though

Comment: I have a question: is it formerly correct to consider this as a sequence? Shouldn't be a considered as a net?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that, when $i$ is near $0$, $\frac{x}{x+i}$ has a singularity at $x=-i$, and the functions blows up near $-i$, so you can never get uniform convergence. It is uniformly convergent in any subset bounded away from $0$.

Comment: Yeah, "sequence" is a bit of a misnomer...

Comment: Maybe for getting sequence in more traditional sense one can view it as an $\left\{\frac{x}{x+\frac{1}{n}}\right\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$

Comment: Yup, definitely not a "sequence", my bad. But thanks to @Sil for saving the day.

Comment: It depends on $x$. If $x=0$, then $\{\frac{x}{x+i}\}=\{0\}$. If $|x|>a$ for some $a>0$, $\{\frac{x}{x+i}\}$ converges uniformly to $1_\mathbb{R}$. If $x\neq0$ near 0$,  $\{\frac{x}{x+i}\}$ converges pointwise to $1_\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Sil you are right. But my question is to invite others to think if there are definitions of convergence in "net theory" more appropriate to this case.
(I am not aware)

Comment: @xpaul Isn't the statement "$|x|>a$ for some $a>0$" equivalent to the statement "$x \neq 0$"?

Comment: @étale-cohomology, it is not.

Comment: @xpaul But, why?